# How to randomly sample from unknown joint distribution in python

Tags: python, statistics

I have the following data

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(100, 20, 100) # these data point come from normal but they could come from any distribution
y = np.random.normal(110, 20, 100) # these data point come from normal but they could come from any distribution
```

with the help of `plotly-express` I can plot their joint distribution

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.density_contour(None, x=x, y=y)
fig.update_traces(contours_coloring="fill", contours_showlabels = True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

I am looking for a way to randomly sample `n` observations from the distribution shown in the plot above (which is unknown).

How could I do that ?

Comment: Wouldn't you only need to pick a random sample from the stack of [x,y]

Comment: No, because I would like to draw a random sample from their distribution, not from the sample

Comment: It depends on the knowledge and assumptions we have/can do. One practical approach would be using KDE over your samples and you get a distribution, from which you can sample. Very similar to the contour plot. Would that work?
Other ways would involve more assumptions, like independence, you could train a NaiveBayes and generate samples from it.
We need to estimate the unknown distribution somehow. If you assume it to be normal/some other known one can do MLE for the parameters.

Comment: @Daraan the practical approach would be suffice, indeed. Not sure how to do it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way via scikit learn.
Hard part is to find hyperparameters that fit your need.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

x = np.random.normal(100, 20, 100) # these data point come from normal but they could come from any distribution
y = np.random.normal(110, 20, 100) 
S = np.vstack((x,y)).T # stack our samples to be of Dx2

kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=2, rtol=0.01)
kde.fit(S)
new_data = kde.sample(100, random_state=0)

kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=2, rtol=0.01)
kde.fit(S)

new_data = kde.sample(100, random_state=1)

sns.kdeplot(x=S[:,0], y=S[:,1], cmap="coolwarm", fill=True)
plt.title("Original Distribution")
plt.show()

sns.kdeplot(x=new_data[:,0], y=new_data[:,1], cmap="coolwarm", fill=True)
plt.title("KDE Distribution")
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]